# MemoryMappedFile: Why does CreateNew throw after a Dispose?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

The code below is throwing, when I try to dispose of and immediately create a `MemoryMappedFile`.

```
memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("MemMapFile1", size);
memMapFile.Dispose();
// Thread.Sleep(20);
memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("MemMapFile1", size);

// throws System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.'
```

However, if one uncomments the line `Thread.Sleep(..)` the sample above is not throwing.

**Q** What is the correct way to dispose of and re-create a `MemoryMappedFile` without triggering an exception? Is there a kind of waiting period before it's possible to create a `MemoryMappedFile` with the same name?

Comment: You need to document the anti-malware product you use, the only way SO users can find out what kind of crapware they need to avoid.

Comment: Which .NET version are you targetting? I just tried this and I get no exception.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I know, what our customers will have in use :(

Comment: @GabrielLuci 4.7.2

Comment: That's what I used in my test. What are you using for `size`? Is it large?

Comment: @GabrielLuci size = 3e6

Comment: Ok, I tested with that size and I am still not getting any exception - using your exact code (no Sleep). Looking at the [source code for `Dispose()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs,611), it doesn't look like it's doing anything asynchronous. It should be completely disposed after the `Dispose()` method returns.